# How to register a Zend\Log Instance in the ServiceManager in ZF2

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-log

I am wondering what is the best way to initiate and re-use a logger instance through the ServiceManager in ZF2.
Of course I can do a simple method to be used in any class, like:

```
public function getLogger () {
        $this->logger = new Logger();
        $this->logger->addWriter(new Writer\Stream('/log/cms_errors.log'));
        return $logger;
    }
```

but I was wondering what is the best way to register a similar structure in the global.php. 
So far I can

add the following to global.php

```
'Zend\Log'=>array(
        'timestampFormat' => 'Y-m-d',
        array(
            'writerName'   => 'Stream',
            'writerParams' => array(
                'stream'   => '/log/zend.log',
            ),
            'formatterName' => 'Simple',            
        ),
    ),
```

If I try invoking it through:

```
$this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Log')
```

I get a :

```
Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Zend\Log
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Add the following data to 'global.php'

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'Zend\Log' => function ($sm) {
            $log = new Zend\Log\Logger();
            $writer = new Zend\Log\Writer\Stream('./data/logs/logfile');
            $log->addWriter($writer);

            return $log;
        },
    ),
),
```

And then you'll be able to call

```
$this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Log')->info('Something...');
```

Comment: @Arthur: Is there a way to be less verbose when calling `$this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Log')->info('Something...');` ?

Comment: This is a working solution until you want to cache your configuration. Because of using a Closure it will fail.
But implementing a Factory Class seems a little bit to unhandy (especially if you want to override in a local.php). Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure if you still looking for this, but you also could use the abstract factory. http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.mvc.services.html#zend-mvc-services-abstract-factories solution will be posted below

Answer (score 11):

Alternatively, and more elegantly, you could setup a log listener and keep your logger decoupled from your app. The `EventManager` is a very powerful component and ZF2 is basically an event driven framework now.

In your `module.php` you could add something like:

```
// Setup the Zend Logger, pseudocode
$logger = new Logger;
$writer = new Writer;
$logger->addWriter($writer);

// Attach a logging listener for the log event on application level, working code
$events = StaticEventManager::getInstance();
$events->attach('*', 'log', function($event) use ($logger) {
    $target = get_class($event->getTarget());
    $message = $event->getParam('message', 'No message provided');
    $priority = (int) $event->getParam('priority', Logger::INFO);
    $message = sprintf('%s: %s', $target, $message);
    $logger->log($priority, $message);
});
```

Then from anywhere, e.g. from a Controller, you can do:

```
$this->getEventManager()->trigger('log', $this, array(
                                                       'priority' => 7, 
                                                       'message' => 'some log message'
                                                      ));
```

Comment: I think that's a great way to do it @markus then all we need to do is implement EventManagerAware or some such

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use the abstract logger factory for configuration instead of the normal factory

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.mvc.services.html#zend-log-loggerabstractservicefactory

```
return array(
    'log' => array(
        'Log\App' => array(
            'writers' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'stream',
                    'priority' => 1000,
                    'options' => array(
                        'stream' => 'data/logs/app.log',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: I would love to learn WHERE we are supposed to put this configuration data. I have been trying to figure that out all afternoon.

Comment: @David: this is the module config (`module/MODULENAME/config/module.config.php`)

Comment: @monkeymoney:  riiiiiight, it's taken me a while to figure this out. the ZF docs typically give configuration examples this way and it's potentially misleading to the noob. if it's meant to go into module.config.php, the example could include /* all your other tons of config data omitted */ for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Please try it again using the absolute path \

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream('log.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger($writer);
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a default database writer object in my bootstrap and registered it in the ServiceManager.

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    ...

    $serviceManager     = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
    $dbAdapter          = $serviceManager->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');

    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Db($dbAdapter, 'log_database_table');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);

    // this is optional but nice to have
    \Zend\Log\Logger::registerErrorHandler($logger);

    $serviceManager->setService('Zend\Log', $logger);
}
```

The AbstractController is an instance of "ServiceLocatorAwareInterface". So I can just call in my controller

```
public function indexAction()
{
    ...

    $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Log')->info('this is a test log message');

    ...
}
```